# Как задать правильно OnClicked для кнопки?

Tags: qt, qml

Задаю кнопку в QML-файле, всё норм:

```
Button {
    signal qmlSignal()
    onClicked: {
        qmlSignal()
    }
}
```

Если задаю её же в UI.QML-файле, то появляется сообщение: "Блоки Javascript не поддерживаются в форме Qt Quick".

Как задать правильно *OnClicked* для кнопки?

Answer (score 2):

Сигнал вы задаёте правильно. Однако согласно [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html), в файлах `*.ui.qml` блоки Javascript не поддерживаются. Выход один - не использовать такие файлы.

Вообще они введены для того, чтобы можно было редактировать форму в дизайнере. Вероятно, дизайнер не может обработать функции, состояния, обработчики сигналов и другие плюшки, поэтому они там отключены. Вообще, на мой взгляд, концепция `*.ui.qml`-файлов ещё сырая, поэтому я её не использую.

Можно просто убрать расширение `ui`.